# how to override function of class while creating its object

Tags: java

I searched stackoverflow and google but couldn't understand. This is my code. 
Class Test and class Tester are in different package and I cannot extend Test class

I want to override token() of class test in get() of class Tester

```
public class Test{
    private String d;
    private String f;

    Test(String d, String f) {
        this. d = d;
        this.f = f;
    }

    public String token(String a, String b) {
        String c; 
        // token() logic
        return c;
    }

}

public class Tester{

    public void get() {
        Test t = new Test (“sample1”, “sample2”);
       // get() logic
    }

}
```

Comment: Which method exactly you want to override?

Comment: @fujy I want to override token() of class Test in get() of class Tester

Comment: It's impossible. You can't override without extending. What can't you extend it?

Comment: @shmosel because I am writing functional test case and cannot extend the class for which I am writing test case. Is there a way out ?

Comment: @user3625750 then you should not change the method that you are editing, I guess

Comment: @fujy but I need to stub the function dependency. Is there no way that I can override token()

Comment: Have you considered mockito for unit testing?

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this

```
Test t = new Test("abc","xyz"){
  @Override
  public String token(String a, String b) {
    // New logic here
  }      
};
```

Comment: I need override token() to return a string. Is that possible ? Also When I am doing the above mentioned thing it throws error "Method doesn't override method from it superclass"

Comment: Yes, it is possible if the original method have the same signature

Comment: you are creating object with default constructor here but in my case I have parameterized constructor. And when I user parameterized constructor when creating object then this throws error "Method doesn't override method from it superclass"

Comment: It should not matter